# Setting up JsFiddle with Vue and vue-tables-2 - t is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jsfiddle, vue-tables-2

I am trying to get help with a particular [vue-tables-2](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2) package implementation. In order to do so, I am trying to set up a jsfiddle and keep getting a `t is undefined` error for even the most basic implementation. Has anyone else run into this error? I suspect it has to do with the importing of dependencies, but cant seem to resolve it.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to get the jsfiddle up and running.

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div id="people">
      <v-server-table url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" :columns="columns" :options="options">
      </v-server-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
Vue.use(VueTables.ServerTable);

new Vue({
    el: "#people",
    data: {
        columns: ['name', 'username'],
        options: {
            // see the options API
        }
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kbpq5vb3/35/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the server is not providing the correct data format `vue-tables-2` is requiring as stated in the docs:

> You need to return a JSON object with two properties:
>
> - data : array - An array of row objects with identical keys.
> - count: number - Total count before limit.

If you can't change what the server returns, you probably have to use the client table where you can grab the data with `axios`.

A minimal client table example using `axios` to grab data.
 https://jsfiddle.net/kbpq5vb3/38/

Answer (score 0):

> If you can't change what the server returns, you probably have to use
>   the client table where you can grab the data with axios.

Not necessarily. You can stick with the server component and use the `requestAdapter` and `responseAdapter` options to mould the request and the response to the expected format.

For Example (Using Github's API):

```
<div id="app">
  <h3>
    Vue Tables 2 - Server Side Demo
  </h3>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div id="people">
      <v-server-table url="https://api.github.com/users/matfish2/repos" :columns="columns" :options="options">
      </v-server-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
Vue.use(VueTables.ServerTable);

new Vue({
  el: "#people",
  methods: {
    formatDate(date) {
      return moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    }
  },
  data: {
    columns: ['name', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'pushed_at'],
    tableData: [],
    options: {
      perPage: 25,
      perPageValues: [25],
      orderBy: {
        column: 'name',
        ascending: true
      },
      requestAdapter(data) {
        return {
          sort: data.orderBy,
          direction: data.ascending ? 'asc' : 'desc'

        }
      },
      responseAdapter({data}) {
        return {
          data,
          count: data.length
        }
      },
      filterable: false,
      templates: {
        created_at(h, row) {
          return this.formatDate(row.created_at);
        },
        updated_at(h, row) {
          return this.formatDate(row.updated_at);
        },
        pushed_at(h, row) {
          return this.formatDate(row.pushed_at);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/matfish2/js4bmdbL/

Comment: I used the solution you suggested as it's more convenient, but I got this error
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at VueComponent.responseAdapter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Builds.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:48:25)